# HQL join on another table

Tags: hibernate, hql

Is it possible to join in Hibernate like in this SQL query `SELECT t1.name FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1_id=t1.id;`? For example:

```
class Table1Entity {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}

class Table2Entity {
    public int id;
    public Table1Entity table1Entity;
}
```

To select all `table1entity` used by `table2entity` using SQL I will call `SELECT t1.name FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1_id=t1.id;`. I know that I can do it like this `SELECT t1.name FROM Table1Entity t1, Table2Entity t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.table1Entity` but I want to use JOIN.

Comment: Go to the Hibernate web site. Navigate to the manual. Search for the chapter about HQL in the table of contents. Search for associations and joins in the table of contents of this chapter. Click on the link. Read. I did all that for you in 10 seconds: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins

Comment: @JB Nizet, I've clarified my question. I read Hibernate documentation but I want to do different join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1 from Table2Entity t2 join t2.table1Entity t1
```